# Select element by class with two identifiers

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class = "a">
    <div class = "a b">
        text
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    alert($(".a").html());
    alert($(".a b").html());
</script>
```

I have to add a script to a HTML page that I didn't write, and in this script I need to select a class that has a name containing two words separated by space. The normal selector won't work. How do I select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of the following will work:

```
alert($(".a").html()); // select elements with class 'a'
alert($(".b").html()); // select elements with class 'b'
alert($(".a.b").html()); // select elements with BOTH classes 'a' AND 'b'
```

Comment: Your first selector will return different results because of the parent element having a class of `a`

Comment: I forgot it was two different classes. Thanks.

Comment: @Curt true, however I just wanted to demonstrate to the OP the syntax involved in selecting classes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert($(".a.b").html());
```